# How to get PartitionId in event hub triggered Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function triggered by Event Hub. I configured the function app in the host.json with a MaxBatchSize of 32. My Event Hub has 6 partitions, and I don't want an event to be processed twice.

So, I need partition ID and sequence number to identify the event uniquely. I would like to save PartitionID and SequenceNumber in my database as primary keys. My function is triggered in input with Array of EventData. Iterating on the array, I can get the SequenceNumber for each message, but I don't know how to get per PartitionID. I tried to include parameter of type PartitionContext among input parameters but it doesn't work.

Here it is my code:

```cs
[FunctionName("EventHubTriggeredFunction")]
public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("events", Connection = "EventHubConnection")]EventData[] eventHubMessages, TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (var message in eventHubMessages)
    {
        using (Stream stream = message.GetBodyStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    //... do something

                    //SequenceNumber: message.SequenceNumber
                    Save(reader.ReadToEnd(), message);

                    //... do something else
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

How can I get PartitionID for each message processed?

Comment: What makes you think your message gets processed twice? Normal behavior is for message to be processed once.

Comment: @PeterBons Got it. I thought a message could be processed multiple times until his expiration (1 day in my case). I'm a beginner with event hub. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: That one day (we are talking about the retention, are we?) is the minimum days the message is kept. In real world I have seen them sitting there for weeks, even months

Comment: You can process older messages but it requires some (manual) steps but it is not default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Define the EventHub trigger [to include Event Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---event-metadata). Then use the [receiverRuntimeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.receiverruntimeinfo?view=azure-dotnet) on the context object.

```
PartitionContext.RuntimeInfo.PartitionId
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but I was using a different name for the parameter (I was using only `PartitionContext context` instead of `PartitionContext PartitionContext`). What the documentation doesn't clearly explain is that the parameter MUST have the exact name of the property. Thank you anyway

Comment: Thanks! By the way, the partition id is also available under `partitionContext.PartitionId`. See full code here: https://gist.github.com/felipecruz91/d5f2df19ed7d7947110142c9fa523b81#file-function1-cs-L20